# C++ mkdir shell utility

Tags: c++

## Abstract

The bash shell utility `mkdir` is a tool used to create directories in most POSIX environments. I thought it would be fun to implement such functionality from C++ and maybe forge in some of my own features in the future. I will be using the C++ library Boost to handle the command line options and the Standard Template Libary (std) to work work with the filesystem. I would appreciate some sustains, nays, and comments on the 50 so lines of code I have written.

## Code

mkdir.cpp

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Define the LOG() macro in order to be able to add
// a logger in the future without too much refactoring
//#define LOG(x) BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(x)
#define LOG(x) std::cout

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Declare the supported options.
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
            ("help,h",                       "produce help message")
            ("parents,p", po::bool_switch(), "no error if existing, make parent directories as needed")
            ("verbose,v", po::bool_switch(), "print a message for each created directory");

    const po::parsed_options parsed = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(desc).allow_unregistered().run();
    const std::vector<std::string> unrecognized =
            collect_unrecognized(parsed.options, po::include_positional);
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(parsed, vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    for (const auto &opt : unrecognized) {
        if (opt[0] == '-') {
            LOG(error) << "Unknown option '" << opt << "'\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (vm.count("help") || argc <= 1) {
        LOG(info) << desc;
        return 1;
    }
    std::error_code ec;
    for (const auto &dir_name : unrecognized) {
        auto path = std::filesystem::absolute(std::filesystem::path(dir_name));
        if (vm["parents"].as<bool>())
            std::filesystem::create_directories(path, ec);
        else
            std::filesystem::create_directory(path, ec);
        if (errno) {
            LOG(error) << "Cannot create directory '" << dir_name
                       << "': " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
            errno = 0;
        } else {
            LOG(info) << "Created directory '" << dir_name << "'\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Try it!

In order to compile this utility the following packages are needed:

`sudo apt install build-essential libboost-program-options-dev`

Then you can compile `mkdir.cpp` with:

`g++ mkdir.cpp -o mkdir -lboost_program_options -std=c++2a`

Then you can test it out with:

`./mkdir <options> <directory names>`

Comment: I was looking at Boost Log as I was already using boost; I had considered using spdlog or glog but decided to consolidate my sources when writing.

Comment: I didn't want to post answer as I don't know C++ at all, but.. The `-m` option is missing, `mkdir -p foo` succeeds even when `foo` is a regular file, `mkdir -p foo/bar` prints an error message but actually works, `-lboost_options` doesn't work on Ubuntu (`-lboost_program_options` does), and `libboost-program-options-dev` takes 145 MB of disk space.

Comment: @oguzismail: Probably going to be disappointed, but presumably you could statically link `libboost-program-options-dev` so it wasn't a runtime dependency, and other users of pre-built binaries would only pay for the disk space consumed by the components actually used?

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's a huge improvement. The resulting binary is 2.5 megabytes in size (whereas `/bin/mkdir` is 88 kilobytes), but yeah, far better than having to install such a ridiculously large library for a program with such limited functionality. Thanks

Comment: @oguzismail: Woo! Always nice to learn the library was written well enough that using parts of it doesn't pull the whole thing in for static linkage. If it provides fat LTO static libs, and the whole program is compiled with LTO enabled it might get even smaller (as it can extract *just* the functions/data it actually uses, inlining where it makes sense, making it even more granular than the "per-object" rules for non-LTO linkage).

Comment: @oguzismail I make a mistake with the linking instructions for boost program options, I have updated it.

Comment: I would rename `unrecognized` to `remaining_args`, or something similar.

Comment: @AShelly yeah makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

Many filesystems allow directory name to start with `-`. To support such names (not just in the `mkdir` context, but in general) POSIX-compliant utility shall treat `--` as an "end-of-options" option.

Boost supports this idea. Everything after `--` is treated as a positional argument. However, as you `include_positional` while collecting unrecognized, the program still treat such directories as options, and refuses to process them.

---

Since you use the `error_code` overload, you should use `ec`, rather than `errno` to report errors. And if you do want to use `errno`, you should not rely on `<cerrno>` being magically included, but `#include <cerrno>` explicitly.

Comment: I had no idea about the end of options option! also, I will revise it to use std::error_code

Answer (score 3):

#### Exit codes

Invoking the help of commands is usually not considered an error, so an exit code of 0 would be expected.

When the real `mkdir` fails to create a directory, it exits with a non-zero value.

#### Decompose work to functions

Currently the `main` function does everything:

- Argument parsing
- Perform appropriate actions

If you plan to build this further,
it already makes sense to decompose a bit more now.

#### Unimplemented features

The verbose flag is not implemented ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use braces around one line in `if` blocks. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311986/why-does-this-if-statement-require-brackets) and [EXP19-C misra rule](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP19-C.+Use+braces+for+the+body+of+an+if%2C+for%2C+or+while+statement).

You do not need `return 0;` at the end. That is the default return value in C++ programs.

Comment: Although return 0 is not needed I would never suggest omitting it.  Leaving it in make's it clear to the reader what is happening, rather than relying on them knowing the somewhat esoteric rule that `int main` doesn't need an explicit return value, but every other function that returns an int does.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX `mkdir` also supports the `-m` option for setting the permissions of the directory as it is created (avoiding race conditions).  Consider supporting that as an enhancement.

Since `std::filesystem` doesn't give expose that aspect of the `mkdir()` system call, you will need to call it directly (and perhaps `#ifdef` to support non-POSIX platforms).  The alternative is a suitable call to `std::filesystem::permissions()` immediately after creating the directory, but that leaves a window of time in which the initial default permissions are effective. That's the kind of thing that leads to security bugs, and a weakness in `std::filesystem` if I'm correct.